# Extract All Links table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, myisam

I have a table just like attached image. [image]

The query i am using to fetch the data is

```
SELECT  message_text 
FROM    messages 
WHERE   conversation_id = "69_P" 
AND     message_type = "text" 
AND     message_text LIKE "%http%" 
LIMIT 3
```

With this query i get the data with links as well as text. So is there any way to grep only links that start with http or www and ends with .domain or any?

Result Output

```
https://www.1and1.com/
Test  https://www.google.com
Test message with link  <a href="https://momentjs.com/docs/">https://momentjs.com/docs/</a>
```

Desired output

```
https://www.1and1.com/
https://www.google.com
https://momentjs.com/docs/
```

Comment: message_text like "http%" and message_text like "%.com"

Comment: Yes  but that returns data mixture of text with link. Please refer the sample data in image row no.3

Comment: like "%http%" returns data mixture, "http%" returns only those that starts with

Comment: Can you give us a more comprehensive list of what all is "good output" and what all is "bad output". This is too vague of a request otherwise.

Comment: @Sanchit i edited the question with the list of output

Comment: @McNets yes i agree that "http%" will only return links that start with http, but that miss out the link with a href tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LIKE '%http%www%domain.com%'
```

will find the lines.  But SQL cannot extract the desired part.  Instead, do the extraction in your application code.

OR...

Redesign your schema to already have the URL in a separate column.